# ember js - value returned from computed property looks cached

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, checkbox, scope

I am having this weird issue while returning an array from a computed property. I got to know the problem exactly (as below), but not sure about solution. Have created a twiddle for demo purpose to explain.

**Case 1**: https://ember-twiddle.com/9910dfea25b6fc4791e3920acca2558d?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

Steps:

a) Check the first checkbox and if we see the value of "arr" in console, the "newprop" property will be added to each object in "arr"

b) Un check the same checkbox, see the console, the same "arr" is returned with that "newprop" still there. 
But I was assuming, it wouldn't have been there, as there is a check for that in if condition.

So, after little troubleshooting, I came up with this identical next twiddle.

**Case 2**:  https://ember-twiddle.com/735750b0a41c4bf87841bc79c6163259?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

perform the same steps and we see that this time the "arr" doesn't have "newprop" when the checkbox is unchecked

The **only difference between twiddle** is that the array (having data/model) in the first one is defined in "getData" itself and in second, its taking it from another computed property "what".

**What I am looking for**: I need to have case 1 twiddle working, but when the checkbox is unchecked, the "arr" should return the actual original "arr" without the "newprop".
Also, need to understand why its happening. The only thing changed is that fetching the data directly inside fn or via another computed property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the main purpose of computed properties. They change if they're dependent keys change. In case 2 you are always redefining your array. In case 1 you're accessing the same array every call.

In case 1 you can add a dependent key on your property list.

```
what: function(){
  var arr = [
      {
        a:"b",
        c: [
          {key:"1"},{key:"2"}
        ]
      },
      {
        a:"f",
        c: [
          {key:"1"},{key:"1"}
        ]
      }
    ];
    return arr;
  }.property('filterSet'), // see here
```

This will *regenerate* your array when the property `filterSet` changes.

EDIT:

[image: proof]

Comment: But I already gave "filterSet" as a dependent in "getData" property,  isn't that right. This is to make sure, that getData is called, every time filterSet changes. And if this is right, getData is always fetching the "what" property as this.get('what') which should always fetch it the original data. please correct me if wrong

Comment: did you do this in the twiddle? because it doesnt change the issue in case 1, in the twiddle.

Comment: @Craicerjack yes I changed the code in the twiddle, and it showed me the desired result in the console.

Comment: @Timm thats odd, I did the same thing and it made no difference to my log. It made sense and it was the first thing I tried. oh well.

Comment: @whyAto8 this is totally true, but your `what` property is not re-evaluated. So instead of giving you the original array, you're getting the old one you modified before. So you could say that ember.js is caching your value as long as the dependent properties do not change.

Comment: @whyAto8  **this.get('what') which should always fetch it the original data** this is what happens in twiddle one. It fetches the data with the new property on it. Its still on it because its the original data and you havent removed the new property from it

Comment: Hey, I tried that, but it didn't work. I realized that I have more levels of computed property to fetch data (as its a big project) for e.g. getData is calling "what", "what" is calling "model2" and "model2" is calling "model1". So, would I need to add the "filterSet" as dependent in all of them, like you did in "what"?

Comment: Forgot to mention, your solution is working in twiddle, but not in my project, hence the above comment/query

Comment: @whyAto8 My rule of thumb is: when you're `get`ing a property in a computed property, then add it to the dependent keys. Is there a way to access your project (e.g. GitHub?)

Comment: @Timm - Let me try with what you propose. And will try to update twiddle so as to replicate my issue. Will update soon here.

Comment: @Timm - Finally, it worked in my code. It was something I was missing, but its okay now. So, to understand, its that if I want "getData" to recompute itself if "filterSet" changes, it will give me cached value until I recompute "what" as well, as "what" is being used in "getData". Would that be right to say?

Comment: @whyAto8 If you want "getData" to recompute itself, you have to change some of its dependent properties. So if you want to recompute "what", you have to change its dependent keys. As I understand you correctly, it's what you're saying.